# Redirect to parameterized name controller

Tags: controller, routes, laravel-5.3

I want redirect to a 'generic' controller function.
I've tried something like this:

```
[1]: Route:get('/ent/create_foreign/{entity}, '{entity}Controller@index');


[2]: Route::get('/ent/create_foreign/{entity}', 
            function($entity){
                return redirect()->action('{$entity}Controller@index');
            }

    );

[3]: Route::get('/ent/create_foreign/{entity}', [
        'as' => 'entity1', 'uses' => 'entity1Controller@index',
        'as' => 'entity2', 'uses' => 'entity2Controller@index'
    ]);
```

[1]: Shows this error:
*Class App\Http\Controllers{entity}Controller does not exist*

[2]: Shows this error:
     *Action App\Http\Controllers{$entity}Controller@index not defined.*
Obviously this Controller and her function were defined.

[3]: It works, but always return the last 'entity'. For this example returns 'entity2'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your single quotes to double quotes for example 2:

```
Route::get('/ent/create_foreign/{entity}', function ($entity) {
    return redirect()->action("{$entity}Controller@index");
});
```

You should be consistent in your class names and file names, and I would suggest following PSR when you can to help with consistency an ease of use.

> Class names MUST be declared in StudlyCaps.

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#namespace-and-class-names

E.g. Lets say there's a "user relations controller"

**Correct**:

```
class UserRelationsController
```

**Incorrect**:

```
class userRelationsController
```

Furthermore, the file name should also be a case-sensitive match e.g.

```
class UserRelationsController // UserRelationsController.php
```

So, if you're were going to use the above route to get redirected to the `UserRelations` controller your url would have to be:

```
/ent/create_foreign/UserRelation
```

and not something like:

```
/ent/create_foreign/userRelation //or
/ent/create_foreign/user_relation
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Shows the same error, but $entity is the value of the parameter.

Comment: **InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 605:                                                                  Action App\Http\Controllers\officeTypesController@index not defined.**             But, this controller and this action are defined.

Comment: @Godiez By any change does the controller name start with a capital O??

Comment: What? Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Godiez You're getting an error with `officeTypesController`, I am asking if your controller is actually named `OfficeTypesController` (Uppercase O at the beginning instead or a lowercase o)

Comment: No, it calls officeTypesController.

Comment: @Godiez I can see that it calls that, I'm asking if it's a case sensitive match for the class name?

Comment: Yes it is. If the class name + action name matches with the definitions, it should work?

Comment: @Godiez Yes, it should work as I've just tested it, however, the only way I've been able to reproduce you error is by being case-insensitive. I've updated my answer to try and convey what I've been trying to say so far